# html2canvas not working inside a php loop

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, html2canvas

I have a javascript function `print()`. It is called by a php loop. It shows 2 copies of an image on a page.

If I run it 1 time, nothing is wrong and below function works. But If I run it more than 1 time, due to promise nature of hmtl2canvas, it corrupts.

I searched for making html2canvas work sync but not much solutions

Also I tried to put it inside a async/await, but none of them works.

```
function print(html_string){

  let leftPanel = 'left'+Date.now(); //create Unique ID
  let rightPanel = 'right'+Date.now(); //create Unique ID

  document.body.innerHTML += "<div style='display:flex;'><div id='"+leftPanel+"'></div><div id='"+rightPanel+"'></div></div>";
  var iframe=document.createElement('iframe');
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);

  var iframedoc=iframe.contentDocument||iframe.contentWindow.document;
  iframedoc.body.innerHTML=html_string;

  html2canvas(iframedoc.body).then(canvas => {
      jQuery("#"+leftPanel).append(canvas);
  });
  html2canvas(iframedoc.body).then(canvas => {
      jQuery("#"+rightPanel).append(canvas);
      document.body.removeChild(iframe);
  });
}
```

**EDIT:**

Above javascript function is called by below php loop:

```
foreach($InvoiceNos as $row){
  $downloadedInvoiceHtml = requestInvoice($row->UUID);
  ?><script>print('<?=$downloadedInvoiceHtml?>');</script><?php
}
```

Comment: This is a "php loop"?

Comment: @Dave no it is a javascript function, edited question and added missing php part.

Comment: Add the html to an array. Then call the function again where you now do `document.body.removeChild(iframe);` and add one to a counter. Stop when counter >= array

Comment: @HOY see my updated example

Comment: @mplungjan thank you I am checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array

```
<script>
const html = [];
<?php 
 foreach($InvoiceNos as $row){
  $downloadedInvoiceHtml = requestInvoice($row->UUID);
  ?>html.push('<?=$downloadedInvoiceHtml?>');<?php
} ?>

let cnt = 0;
function print(){
  if (cnt >= html.length) return; // stop
  $("body").append(`<div style='display:flex;'><div></div><div></div></div>`);
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = html[cnt]
  html2canvas(div).then(canvas => {
    $("body div:last-child div").append(canvas);
    cnt++;
    print()
  });
}
print()
</script>
```

Alternatively

```
<?php 
 foreach($InvoiceNos as $row){
  $downloadedInvoiceHtml = requestInvoice($row->UUID);
  ?><div style="display:flex"><div class="html"><?=$downloadedInvoiceHtml?></div></div>
  } ?>
<script>
let cnt = 0;
const $html = $(".html");
function print(){
  if (cnt >= $html.length) return; // stop
  $current = $html[cnt]
  html2canvas($html).then(canvas => {
    $current.empty().append(canvas);
    $current.after($current.clone(true);
    cnt++;
    print()
  });
}
print()
</script>
```

Comment: there are some minor problems in code, but the structure helped me solve my issue! Thanks. :)

Comment: Yeah, I did not make a working example because I did not have a [mcve] to begin with

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a `print()` on each loop, simply store the contents in a variable and print the results when you're done.